# Accio file! File finding utility

Tags: performance, beginner, algorithm, c

I decided to spend the last few days writing a file-finding utility in C (written for GNU/Linux) and would *love* to be told if this code [makes my ass look fat](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stack-overflow/141#141). I want to learn the *right* way to write C code so that I can contribute to the open source community (not that all open source code is written in C)!

This is the first time I write something of worth in a language other than Java so I would like it if you would comment on the visual aspects of the code as well as the implementation (better ways to accomplish the same thing).

**Usage**:

```
$ programName startingDir fileToMatch
```

Example:

```
$ ./accioFile / myFileICantFind.txt
```

Note: the program only handles file names for the second argument, not paths.

Outputs either the absolute path of the first match or "File not found".

Example:

```
/path/to/myFileICantFind.txt
```

The code itself doesn't do any input checking because that wasn't the goal of the exercise so please ignore that part.

Essentially, the program uses a breadth-first search starting in the base directory to find the requested file. The base directory is added to a queue and then the directory walk begins. It gets the first element of the queue and checks all the files in the directory, enqueue-ing any directories it finds and checking for the requested file. It then repeats the process until it runs out of items in the queue or finds the file.

I also want to note that I've run the code through Memcheck and am happy to report that there are no memory leaks (something I'm quite proud of, actually).

List of methods:

- `void enqueue(...)`: Adds item to queue
- `char *dequeue()`: Removes item from queue
- `void cleanup_queue()`: Deletes remaining items in queue
- `int isValidDirectory(...)`: Checks whether parameter is `.` or `..`
- `char *readDir(...)`: Walks directory tree
- `int main(...)`: Main method

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct node_t {
  char *path;
  struct node_t *next;
} Node;

Node *head = NULL;
Node *tail = NULL;

void enqueue(char *path) {
  Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  node->path = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(node->path, path);
  node->next = NULL;

  if (head == NULL && tail == NULL) {
    head = tail = node;
  } else {
    tail->next = node;
    tail = node;
  }
}

char *dequeue() {
  char *path;

  if (head == NULL && tail == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  path = head->path;

  if (head == tail) {
    free(head);
    head = tail = NULL;
  } else {
    Node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
  }

  return path;
}

void cleanup_queue() {
  Node *temp;
  while (head != NULL) {
    temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp->path);
    free(temp);
  }
}

int isValidDirectory(char *dir) { /* We want to avoid ".." and "." */
  if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '\0') {
    return 0;
  } else if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '.' && dir[2] == '\0') {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

char *readDir(char *file) {

  DIR *d; /* Directory stream */
  struct dirent *dir; /* Directory object */
  struct stat file_stat; /* Stats object */
  char *base; /* Absolute value of current directory */
  char *path = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char)); /* Allocate space for path */

  /* While items are still left in the queue... */
  while ((base = dequeue()) != NULL) {
    /* If user doesn't have read access, skip it */
    if (access(base, R_OK) != 0) {
      free(base);
      continue;
    }

    /* Open directory stream */
    d = opendir(base);
    if (d) { /* If stream isn't null... */
      for (int i = 0; (dir = readdir(d)) != NULL; i++) { /* For each file in the current directory... */

    if (strcmp(base, "/") != 0) { /* If base path isn't root... */
      sprintf(path, "%s/%s", base, dir->d_name); /* Concatenate base and d_name with a separator */
    } else {
      sprintf(path, "%s%s", base, dir->d_name); /* Don't use separator */
    }

    if (strcmp(dir->d_name, file) == 0) { /* If d_name and file being searched for are equal... */
      free(base); /* Don't forget to close the door on your way out! */
      closedir(d);
      return path; /* return */
    }

    lstat(path, &file_stat); /* Get stats for path */
    if (S_ISDIR(file_stat.st_mode) && isValidDirectory(dir->d_name)) { /* If path points to directory and it isn't '.' or '..'... */
      enqueue(path); /* Add the directory to the queue */
    }
      }

      free(base);
    }

    closedir(d); /* Be nice and close the directory stream :) */
  }
  free(path);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *search = *(argv + 2);
  char baseDir[PATH_MAX];
  int failedFlag = 0;
  realpath(*(argv + 1), baseDir);

  enqueue(baseDir);

  char *file = readDir(search);
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("File not found\n");
    failedFlag = 1;
  } else {
    printf("%s\n", file);
  }

  free(file);

  cleanup_queue();

  return failedFlag;
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? I'd just like some constructive criticism. Also, thank you @Jamal for editing the question's format, this was my first question.

Comment: @vnp, I've rollbacked your edit that "fixed indentation", as it made the indentation inconsistent and probably not what was actually written and reviewable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some observations, in no particular order:

- ```
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->path = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char));
  ```

  That first one is (arguably) better written as `malloc(sizeof *node)`.  This is a useful style to adopt, as it saves embarrassment when you changed the type of `node` and don't spot the second use of the type.

  In the second one, `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, so the multiplication is a no-op and can be omitted.

  Note that in both cases, it's important to check that the allocation succeeded (did not return a null pointer) before using the memory.  For a utility like this, the best response to allocation failure is to exit early with a non-zero status.
- ```
    node->path = malloc(PATH_MAX);
    strcpy(node->path, path);
  ```

  There's no need to allocate `PATH_MAX` characters for storage, as we only write `strlen(path)` plus a terminating NUL:

  ```
    node->path = malloc(strlen(path)+1);
    strcpy(node->path, path);
  ```

  (In comments, you expressed uncertainty about using `strlen()` here - see footnote)
- In a boolean context `(dir = readdir(d)) != NULL` can be written simply as `(dir = readdir(d))` (I keep the redundant parens as an indicator that assignment is intended, rather than a typo; this is a convention that GCC understands, and possibly other compilers too).
- The local variable `i` is modified in the `for` loop, but never used.  We can simplify to `while ((dir=readdir(d)))` instead.
- Naming: avoid names like `readDir` that are pronounced the same as standard functions (`readdir`).
- Reduce scope.  For example, by moving `temp` into the `while` loop in `cleanup_queue`, we can make it constant:

  ```
  void cleanup_queue() {
      while (head) {
          Node *const temp = head;
          head = head->next;
          free(temp->path);
          free(temp);
      }
  }
  ```
- Another simplification: instead of testing the characters individually in `isValidDirectory()`, it's probably clearer to use `strcmp()` consistently:

  ```
  int isValidDirectory(const char *dir) {
       /* true unless dir is ".." or "." */
       return strcmp(".", dir) && strcmp("..", dir);
  }
  ```

  As part of this, observe that the pattern

  ```
  if (bool_expr)
      return 1;
  else
      return 0;
  ```

  is exactly equivalent to just

  ```
  return bool_expr;
  ```
- Instead of testing for `base` equal to `/`, we should probably test for *any* path ending in `/` (since a user-supplied argument may well end in the separator):

  ```
          /* compose name, adding separator if needed */
          sprintf(path, "%s%s%s",
                        base,
                        (base[strlen(base)-1] == '/' ? "" : "/"),
                        dir->d_name);
  ```
- When printing the failure message:

  ```
  printf("File not found\n");
  ```

  Prefer to use the standard error stream:

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
  ```

  This makes the program play nicely with others.
- Check arguments

  ```
    char *search = *(argv + 2);
  ```

  That's normally written

  ```
    char *search = argv[2];
  ```

  But in either case, this gives you undefined behaviour if the user doesn't supply two or more arguments.  You should check `argc`, and exit early with a usage message if `argc < 3`.
- Check return values of library functions - for example, we call `realpath()` with a user-supplied filename.  There are several ways this can fail (as seen in the man page), and `baseDir` will then have undefined contents.

---

**Footnote**:  It's perfectly fine to use `strlen()` on any null-terminated string, regardless of location. Perhaps you're thinking of warnings about using `sizeof` on string variables - that's when you need to really understand what's a pointer and what's an array.  Here's what an array type looks like:

```
const char a[] = "Array"; // sizeof a == 6
                          //             { 'A', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '\0' }
                          // strlen(a) == 5
```

But if we access the array using a pointer to its elements, `sizeof` measures the pointer type, though `strlen()` still counts string characters:

```
const char *p = a; // sizeof p == sizeof (const char*)
                   //             (often 4 or 8, depending on your system)
                   // strlen(p) == 5
```

Note that the assignment might be camouflaged somewhat:

```
void foo(const char p[]) {
     // p is a pointer here, *not* an array!
}
```

Comment: You and 2 others missed one particular check I feel is absolutely necessary, @user3629249 did get it. In C++ new() throws an exception if it fails, however, malloc() in C does not, it returns NULL.. Proper error handling is to check if `malloc()` returned NULL or not.

Comment: Good point, @pacman - I'm normally quite good at picking up on that one; I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

- Both branches of adding node in `enqueue` make `tail = node`. Make it explicit:

  ```
      if (head == NULL) {
          head = node;
      } else {
          tail->next = node;
      }
      tail = node;
  ```

  Here I intentionally do not test for `tail == NULL`. It is an invariant of the list; if you wish to be sure, assert it in both branches:

  ```
      if (head == NULL) {
          assert(tail == NULL);
          head = node;
      } else {
          assert(tail != NULL);
          tail->next = node;
      }
      tail = node;
  ```

  Similarly, node removal shall be more explicit:

  ```
       Node * tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       if (head == 0) {
           assert(tmp == head);
           tail = NULL;
       }
       free(tmp);
  ```
- `access` followed by an actual access is a classic TOCTOU race. Testing for what `opendir` returns is just enough.

  Meanwhile, the `lstat` return value shall also be tested. It it failed, you cannot trust what `file_stat` tells you.
- I honestly do not understand why do you special case `base` being `"/"`.
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. It is generally considered a bad form to use it as a factor.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I just wanted to address "I honestly do not understand why do you special case base being '/'." The special case is because if someone provides the value "/" as the base dir, the following paths will look like "//proc" and "//lost+found".

Answer (score 5):

> first time I write something of worth in a language other than Java

Good start

---

OP already has some good reviews, only a few crumbs are left.

1. As the data pointed to by `file` are un-changed, uses `const` to allow wider use of `readDir()` and some potential optimizations.  Same for others

   ```
   // char *readDir(char *file) {
   char *readDir(const char *file) {

   // int isValidDirectory(char *dir) {
   int isValidDirectory(const char *dir) {
   ```
2. Concerning multiplying by the size of the data, which in this case is 1,  either drop the `sizeof(char)` or multiply with the size of the de-referenced pointer.  I recommend to lead with the `sizeof` part as that better ensures math is done with at least `size_t` math - even though the order makes no difference here - it does so in more complex calculations.

   ```
   // path = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char));
   path = malloc(sizeof *path * PATH_MAX);

   // node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   node = malloc(sizeof *Node);
   ```
3. When code has an early `return`, consider simpler code. (Additional simplification possible too)

   ```
   // OP's
   if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '\0') {
     return 0;
   } else if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '.' && dir[2] == '\0') {
     return 0;
   } else {
     return 1;
   }
   ```

   ```
   // Suggested
   if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '\0') {
     return 0;
   } 
   if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '.' && dir[2] == '\0') {
     return 0;
   }
   return 1;
   ```

   ```
   // or
   if (dir[0] == '.') {
     if (dir[1] == '\0' || (dir[1] == '.' && dir[2] == '\0')) {
       return 0;
     }
   } 
   return 1;
   ```
4. "List of methods:" --> In C these are best called "List of functions:"

Comment: I meant to mention something like point 1, but forgot - thanks for addressing that one!  As to point 3, I've got something similar, but also folded `if (bool_expr) return 1; else return 0;` into `return bool_expr;` without further explanation - do you think I should expand on that point?

Comment: @toby Expand as you wish if it makes [the answer better](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185137/29485).  If  inspired by others, add a credit

Answer (score 3):

regarding:

```
char *readDir(char *file) {
```

the function: `readdir()`, all lower case, is a well known function that was exposed with the header file: `dirent.h`

It is a poor programming practice to write functions with the same name (even with some capitalization change) as a system function.  Suggest changing that function name.

regarding:

```
char *path = malloc(PATH_MAX * sizeof(char)); /* Allocate space for path */
```

1. the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.
2. always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

regarding:

```
if (strcmp(base, "/") != 0) { /* If base path isn't root... */
  sprintf(path, "%s/%s", base, dir->d_name); /* Concatenate base and d_name with a separator */
} else {
  sprintf(path, "%s%s", base, dir->d_name); /* Don't use separator */
}
```

BEFORE using the field `d_name`, always check the 'type' of the entry to be sure it is a directory and not a regular file or a link, etc.

for ease of readability and understanding:

1. consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level 4 spaces as that is visible even with variable width fonts.
2. follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Treat the closing brace '}'. as a separate statement.
3. separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.

the posted code is calling `dequeue()` before calling `enqueue()`  so the code will (probably) fail on the very first loop.

There may be more than one file in the file system those name matches the 'search' name, so should complete the search, not exiting.immediately.